# how to provide validation on a login from components in coreui

Tags: vue.js

I am complete new to coreui and vue js,i dont know how its function are work .I have a templete but i dont know how to validate it.can any oe help me to validate it,i use v-model,v-validate,arial-required but these functions are not working this is my login page where i simple define a username and password but i dont know how to validate it

Login.vue

```
<template>
<div id="login">
  <CContainer class="d-flex content-center min-vh-100">
    <CRow>
      <CCol>
        <CCardGroup>
          <CCard class="p-4">
            <CCardBody>
              <CForm>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                <CInput 
                  placeholder="Username"
                  autocomplete="usernameemail"

                >
                  <template #prepend-content><CIcon name="cil-user"/></template>
                </CInput>
                <CInput 
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  autocomplete="curent-password"
                >
                  <template #prepend-content><CIcon name="cil-lock-locked"/></template>
                </CInput>
                <CRow>
                  <CCol col="6" class="text-left">
                    <CButton color="primary" class="px-4" @click="direDisplay">Login</CButton>
                  </CCol>
                  <CCol col="6" class="text-right">
                    <CButton color="link" class="px-0">Forgot password?</CButton>
                    <CButton color="link" class="d-md-none">Register now!</CButton>
                  </CCol>
                </CRow>
              </CForm>
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
          <CCard
            color="primary"
            text-color="white"
            class="text-center py-5 d-sm-down-none"
            body-wrapper
          >
            <h2>Sign up</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <CButton
              color="primary"
              class="active mt-3"
            >
              Register Now!
            </CButton>
          </CCard>
        </CCardGroup>
      </CCol>
    </CRow>
  </CContainer>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Login',

      methods:{
        direDisplay(){
      this.$router.push('/Dashboard') 
        }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Try using Vuelidate

Comment: Why is everyone recommending Vuelidate when CoreUI has its own validation-related props (https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#shared-props-and-slots)? What does Vuelidate offer more?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Vuelidate`. To explain in brief, you can import Vuelidate in your project and the built-in validators.

```
import { email, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
    validations: {
          email: {
              email,
              required
          }
    }
}
```

Once you import `Vuelidate` in your project, it makes a validations object available with which you can specify the validation mappings. These mappings are available in the template via `$v` and can be updated on events as

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="data.email" @blur="$v.email.$touch()">
```

This is just the beginning and you should learn more from online sources.

Comment: when i do this type of validation i get error  property or method "$v" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Comment: Did you import `Vuelidate` into your project?

Comment: yes, import { required,minlength,username,password } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

Comment: No, these are the helper functions by vuelidate. Did you `import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'`? Please follow a tutorial to do so

Comment: yes i import that but it cannot work,I dont know how to  solve this type of issue